# Bootstrap list loses alignment if I collapse to xs / sm, then return (resize) back to md or lg in Google Chrome.

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

here is a jsFiddle. The mobile design is not complete, but the behavior of collapsing to sm and xs then expanding back to md or lg will show what is happening. Click 'run' again to return the view to my desired layout once it is distorted:

http://jsfiddle.net/Noobster/HB7LU/15709/

It looks as desired when the screen is at md or lg, but once you collapse (sm xs), then resize back to md or lg, it distorts the alignment of the list items.

I want to contribute quality questions. After reviewing the example in the fiddle, let me know if you need further clarification on what I'm asking.

```
.labelRow{}
```

is the css  / sass for the list in the fiddle.

- This seems to be a chrome issue. It's working as expected in firefox.

Comment: The Sass tag was removed on purpose.  Unless you have a Sass->CSS compilation issue, this is not a Sass problem.  Do not add the tag back in.  Also, not circumvent the "links to jsfiddle must come with code" rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try setting the column to display: table-cell, since the row is display table.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `display: block;` from the `ul li` in the media query.

If you want to have them all in one columns, change the width to 100% instead for mobile.

Comment: yeah, I see that works. But, for mobile, I am wanting to swap it to display block.